# Block all ports except 22 and 80 in CentOS

Tags: iptables, centos-6

How do I block all ports except 22 and 80 in CentOS 6.2 64bit.

Comment: Super lazy question (google is your friend). Also you should have asked something like "How do I block all ports except for a few in centos 6"

Answer (score 2):

Try;

http://bit.ly/1ceUz4w

If you're super lazy;

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-a-basic-ip-tables-configuration-on-centos-6

IPTables is a good way to implement what you need.